# FFmpeg create muted audio file from video without audio

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a webm file with only the video track. I would like to know if is it possible to create a new file with an only muted audio track of the same duration as the video file. Let's say that we have a webm vp8 and I want to create another file with the same duration with a muted AAC track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using pipes, like this.

```
ffmpeg -an -i in.webm -f lavfi -i anullsrc -c:v copy -c:a aac -shortest -fflags +shortest -max_interleave_delta 200M -f nut - | ffmpeg -f nut -i - -vn -c copy silent.m4a
```

Comment: Thanks @Gyan. If the input file is an mp4. What should I change in the command?

Comment: You can use whichever input you want after `-i`. So replace `-i in.webm` with `-i in.mp4`